# Python list comprehension mirroring values

Tags: python, list-comprehension

I tried to figure out the following problem through list comprehension but I couldn't make it work. I will show you how I solved the problem using a loop and a list comprehension.

So, I have a list that can have 0 to 6 elements in a range(6) and when I apply my function on it I want to change the values, as shown here:

```
l = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
mirror = [5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0]
```

I don't want to just rotate the array by 180 degrees but I actually want to replace the values. For example, my list looks like this now:

```
l = [2, 5]
```

Then l_inverted list should look like this:

```
l_inverted = [3, 0]
```

I came up with a regular way to solve it but ever since I started learning Python I've preferred list comprehensions.

```
l = [0, 3, 5]
mirror = [5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0]
i = 0
for element in l:
    l[i] = mirror[element]
    i += 1
```

This actually inverts the l list. Here's my approach using a list comprehension:

```
l = [3, 5]
mirror = [5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0]
for element in l:
    print(element)
    l = [mirror[element] if x==element else x for x in l]
```

This works fine.
Until:

```
l = [0, 3, 5]
mirror = [5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0]
for element in l:
    print(element)
    l = [mirror[element] if x==element else x for x in l]
```

So it will replace 5 with 0, 2 with 3 and both 5s (the new one too) become 0. Obviously, I don't want it like that.

Should I stick to the working solution or is there a smooth way to solve it with list comprehensions? I'm trying to practice list comprehensions at all times but it's not fully in my brain yet. Thanks a lot.

Comment: what's wrong with `l = list(reversed(l))`?

Comment: How does "2,5' "invert" into "3,0"?!

Comment: wait, do you actually want to take `5` minus each element?

Comment: Sorry, doesn't seem to be clear enough. 2 converts into 3 because they have the same index if we look at the full list of l and the full list of mirror. If that makes sense.. else I"ll try to explain it differently :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want it as a list comprehension:

```
>> l = [0, 3, 5]
>> mirror = [5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0]
>> l_inverted = [mirror[x] for x in l]
>> l_inverted
[5, 2, 0]
```

Comment: Idk how I couldn't come up with this but this was what I was thinking of. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You are drowning in a spoonful of water and trying to take us with you. 
You are using bad naming conventions that make your simple problem complicated to comprehend.

```
orig = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
orig_rev = l[::-1]

selector = [0, 3, 5]

result = [orig_rev[i] for i in selector]
print(result )  # [5, 2, 0]
```

Comment: Sorry I'm new to this, I tried my best being as accurate as possible.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your first two examples, it seems you are looking for the ***complement*** of each list value according to some base, similar to [ones' complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ones%27_complement).  You could either hard-code the base as 5 or whatever, or you could assume it's the maximum number in the list and calculate it.  Here's a solution for the latter:

**Concept**

```
<this complement> = <max value in list> - <this value>
```

**Code**

```
values = [0, 3, 2, 4, 5]
max_value = max(values)
complements = [max_value - value for value in values]
print complements
```

**Result**

```
[5, 2, 3, 1, 0]
```